# Samba mounts hangs the system

Tags: mount, samba, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, cluster

I set up a cluster using pcs with 2 nodes + quorum

```
[root@konor2 etc]# pcs status
Cluster name: wildflycluster
Status of pacemakerd: 'Pacemaker is running' (last updated 2023-06-01 09:52:35 +02:00)
Cluster Summary:
  * Stack: corosync
  * Current DC: konor2c (version 2.1.5-7.el9-a3f44794f94) - partition with quorum
  * Last updated: Thu Jun  1 09:52:36 2023
  * Last change:  Thu Jun  1 06:03:53 2023 by root via cibadmin on konor2c
  * 2 nodes configured
  * 4 resource instances configured

Node List:
  * Online: [ konor2c ]
  * OFFLINE: [ konor1c ]

Full List of Resources:
  * Resource Group: wildfly-resources-grp:
    * wildfly-vip       (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):         Started konor2c
    * wildfly-server    (systemd:wildfly):       Started konor2c
    * smb-mount-it      (systemd:home-jboss-mnt-protector-IT.mount):     Started konor2c
    * smb-mount-transmek        (systemd:home-jboss-mnt-protector-transmek.mount):       Started konor2c

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

In `/etc/fstab` there are the following SMB mounts:

```
//protector/data         /home/jboss/mnt/protector/data          cifs  noauto,vers=3.0,_netdev,credentials=/etc/ucr/vu-d.crd,domain=unmz,uid=wildfly,noexec,nosuid,mapchars,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,nounix,nobrl 0
//protector/IT         /home/jboss/mnt/protector/IT          cifs  noauto,vers=3.0,_netdev,credentials=/etc/ucr/vu-d.crd,domain=unmz,uid=wildfly,noexec,nosuid,mapchars,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,nounix,nobrl 0 0
//protector/transmek   /home/jboss/mnt/protector/transmek    cifs  noauto,vers=3.0,_netdev,credentials=/etc/ucr/vu-d.crd,domain=unmz,uid=wildfly,noexec,nosuid,mapchars,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,nounix,nobrl 0 0
```

Using mount the share using the mount command, I can mount them using systemctl. Then it works OK, but after some time (it can be from 2 to 20 hours - I have not found a trigger yet). Process cifsiod starts to consume a lot of CPU and after some time it consumes all CPUs and the VM has to be restarted manually from VMware vCenter. In `/var/log/messages`, there are messages like these:

```
May 30 22:10:00 konor1 systemd[1]: Finished system activity accounting tool.
May 30 22:11:20 konor1 pacemaker-controld[419997]: notice: State transition S_IDLE -> S_POLICY_ENGINE
May 30 22:11:20 konor1 pacemaker-schedulerd[419996]: notice: Calculated transition 196, saving inputs in /var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-104.bz2
May 30 22:11:20 konor1 pacemaker-controld[419997]: notice: Transition 196 (Complete=0, Pending=0, Fired=0, Skipped=0, Incomplete=0, Source=/var/lib/pacemaker/pengine/pe-input-104.bz2): Complete
May 30 22:11:20 konor1 pacemaker-controld[419997]: notice: State transition S_TRANSITION_ENGINE -> S_IDLE
May 30 22:19:12 konor1 pacemaker-controld[419997]: notice: High CPU load detected: 3.990000
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 26s! [kworker/0:0:1456407]
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: Modules linked in: tls nls_utf8 cifs cifs_arc4 rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core cifs_md4 dns_resolver nft_fib_inet nft_fib_ipv4 nft_fib_ipv6 nft_fib nft_reject_inet nf_
reject_ipv4 nf_reject_ipv6 nft_reject nft_ct nft_chain_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 rfkill ip_set nf_tables nfnetlink vsock_loopback vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common vm
w_vsock_vmci_transport vsock sunrpc vfat fat intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common vmw_balloon rapl pcspkr vmw_vmci i2c_piix4 joydev xfs libcrc32c sr_mod cdrom ata_generic vmwgfx drm_ttm_helper ttm d
rm_kms_helper ahci syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops libahci ata_piix sd_mod drm t10_pi sg crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel libata ghash_clmulni_intel vmxnet3 vmw_pvscsi se
rio_raw dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod fuse
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 1456407 Comm: kworker/0:0 Kdump: loaded Not tainted 5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64 #1
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware7,1/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS VMW71.00V.18227214.B64.2106252220 06/25/2021
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: Workqueue: cifsiod smb2_reconnect_server [cifs]
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x21/0x30
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: Code: 82 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 66 90 ba 01 00 00 00 8b 07 85 c0 75 0d f0 0f b1 17 85 c0 75 f2 c3 cc cc cc cc f3 90 <eb> e9 e9 38 fe ff ff 0f 1f 84
 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 57
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb00087187d78 EFLAGS: 00000202
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: ffff9cdc14b62800 RCX: 000000364c970000
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9cdc14b60828
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: RBP: ffff9cdc14b60828 R08: ffffb00087187e38 R09: 0000000000000000
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: R10: ffffb00087187ce8 R11: ffff9cdc3594dc00 R12: 0000000000000000
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: R13: ffff9cdc14b60800 R14: 000000000000ffff R15: 000000000000ffff
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9cdcb9c00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: CR2: 00007fa14a882000 CR3: 00000001ab010003 CR4: 00000000000606f0
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: Call Trace:
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: <TASK>
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: _raw_spin_lock+0x25/0x30
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: smb2_reconnect.part.0+0x3f/0x5f0 [cifs]
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: ? set_next_entity+0xda/0x150
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: smb2_reconnect_server+0x203/0x5f0 [cifs]
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: ? __tdx_hypercall+0x80/0x80
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: process_one_work+0x1e5/0x3c0
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: ? rescuer_thread+0x3a0/0x3a0
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: worker_thread+0x50/0x3b0
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: ? rescuer_thread+0x3a0/0x3a0
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: kthread+0xd6/0x100
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
May 30 22:19:13 konor1 kernel: </TASK>
May 30 22:19:23 konor1 corosync-qdevice[933368]: Server didn't send echo reply message on time
May 30 22:19:34 konor1 corosync-qdevice[933368]: Connect timeout
May 30 22:19:41 konor1 kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 52s! [kworker/0:0:1456407]
```

And so on... Still repeating... In `corosync.log` I can find the following messages (from a different day)

```
I, [2023-05-22T09:57:32.101 #00000]     INFO -- : 200 GET /remote/get_configs?cluster_name=wildflycluster (10.10.51.46) 3.75ms
I, [2023-05-22T10:06:42.066 #00000]     INFO -- : 200 GET /remote/get_configs?cluster_name=wildflycluster (10.10.51.47) 4.13ms
I, [2023-05-22T10:06:42.271 #00012]     INFO -- : Config files sync started
I, [2023-05-22T10:06:42.272 #00012]     INFO -- : SRWT Node: konor2 Request: get_configs
I, [2023-05-22T10:06:42.272 #00012]     INFO -- : Connecting to: https://konor2:2224/remote/get_configs?cluster_name=wildflycluster
I, [2023-05-22T10:06:42.272 #00012]     INFO -- : SRWT Node: konor1 Request: get_configs
I, [2023-05-22T10:06:42.272 #00012]     INFO -- : Connecting to: https://konor1:2224/remote/get_configs?cluster_name=wildflycluster
I, [2023-05-22T10:07:05.272 #00012]     INFO -- : Config files sync finished
I, [2023-05-22T10:07:35.262 #00000]     INFO -- : 200 GET /remote/get_configs?cluster_name=wildflycluster (10.10.51.46) 7.95ms
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.015 #00013]     INFO -- : Config files sync started
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.016 #00013]     INFO -- : SRWT Node: konor2 Request: get_configs
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.016 #00013]     INFO -- : Connecting to: https://konor2:2224/remote/get_configs?cluster_name=wildflycluster
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.016 #00013]     INFO -- : SRWT Node: konor1 Request: get_configs
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.016 #00013]     INFO -- : Connecting to: https://konor1:2224/remote/get_configs?cluster_name=wildflycluster
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.016 #00013]     INFO -- : No response from: konor1 request: get_configs, error: couldnt_connect
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.016 #00013]     INFO -- : No response from: konor2 request: get_configs, error: couldnt_connect
I, [2023-05-22T10:16:42.016 #00013]     INFO -- : Config files sync finished
```

It looks like the server lost a network connectivity

I have another single VM (not clustered) with the same SMB mounts and it has the mounts mounted for days without any issues. When I operate the cluster without SMB mounts, it runs for days without issues. This situation is present on both VMs of the cluster. I also reinstalled them, but it is still the same.

Have you ever seen anything similar? Do you have any recommendations on how to troubleshoot it?
Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered this issue when running Red Hat 9.2.

Red Hat identified it as a bug in this ticket on their Customer Support Portal, currently tagged "Solution in Progress":
[RHEL9.2: soft lockups due to smb2_reconnect thread spinning on tc_lock](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7013742)

The current workaround is to use a kernel from RHEL 9.1.

In my case, using kernel 5.14.0-162.18.1.el9_1.x86_64 eliminated the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).